# Flex list control itemrenderer issue

Tags: image, flex4, itemrenderer

I am working on a small photo Gallery. I create a xml file and try to link it to my List control with itemrenderer. However, when I tried to save the file, I got access of undefined property "data" error. I thought we are suppose to use "data" to refer the current row of the data object. Here is my code...and thanks a lot!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
 <fx:Declarations>
  <fx:Model id="pictureXML" source="data/pictures.xml"/>
  <s:ArrayList id="pictureArray" source="{pictureXML.picture}"/>
 </fx:Declarations>



 <s:List id="pictureGrid" dataProvider="{pictureArray}" 
   horizontalCenter="0" top="20">
  <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
    <s:HGroup>
     <mx:Image source="images/big/{data.source}" /> // where the error happen
     <s:Label text="{data.caption}"/> // where the error happen
    </s:HGroup>   

   </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
 </s:List>


</s:Application>
```

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<album>
   <picture>
   <source>city1.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 1</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city2.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 2</caption>
   </picture>
     <picture>
   <source>city3.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 3</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city4.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 4</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city5.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 5</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city6.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 6</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city7.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 7</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city8.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 8</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city9.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 9</caption>
   </picture>
    <picture>
   <source>city10.jpg </source>
   <caption>City View 10</caption>
   </picture>
</album>
```

I appreciate any helps!!!

Comment: Does the error only happen on the mx:Image line or both mx:Image and s:Label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<s:List id="pictureGrid" dataProvider="{pictureArray}" 
   horizontalCenter="0" top="20">
  <s:itemRenderer>
   <fx:Component>
      <s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:HGroup>
     <mx:Image source="images/big/{data.source}" /> // where the error happen
     <s:Label text="{data.caption}"/> // where the error happen
    </s:HGroup>   
    </s:ItemRenderer>
   </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
 </s:List>
```

Try This! It would work

Answer (score 1):

I think that the data property that you are trying to access is out of scope because it is within an in-line itemRenderer. Try abstracting your ItemRenderer into it's own component instead of doing it as an in-line component.

You may also be able to reach into the in-line itemRenderer to get access to each items data property but this is cleaner....

I've separated your IR into its own component and everything seems fine...

```
<!-- YOUR LIST -->
<s:List id="pictureGrid" dataProvider="{pictureArray}" 
                horizontalCenter="0" top="20"
                itemRenderer="TestRenderer"/> // reference new IR class here

<!-- NEW ITEMRENDERER CLASS -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true">

        <s:HGroup>
            <mx:Image source="images/big/{data.source}" /> 
            <s:Label text="{data.caption}"/> 
        </s:HGroup>   

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 override public function set data(value:Object):void
   {
                super.data = value;
                if (data == null)
                    return;

                irImage.source = data.path; 
                            irText.text = data.caption   

  }


<s:HGroup>
            <mx:Image id="irImage" /> 
            <s:Label id="irText"text="{data.caption}"/> 
</s:HGroup>
```

if this is not work then tell me.